Running Supabase locally, 'relation does not exist' issue
I am working with a GitHub repo and trying to get the project to run locally on my machine. I am not the original creator of the project.
The .env file has a NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL and NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY and SUPABASE_SERVICE_ROLE_KEY. I set up a Supabase account and was able to set NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL and NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY, but SUPABASE_SERVICE_ROLE_KEY I am not sure what to set.
Anyways, when I run npx next dev, I get the following issue.

   ▲ Next.js 14.0.4
   - Local:        http://localhost:3000
   - Environments: .env.local


 ✓ Ready in 10.6s
 ○ Compiling / ...
 ✓ Compiled / in 6s (2966 modules)
(node:41257) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
 ✓ Compiled in 1370ms (1227 modules)
Supabase error: {
  code: '42P01',
  details: null,
  hint: null,
  message: 'relation "public.generations" does not exist'
}
Error fetching characters: {
  code: '42P01',
  details: null,
  hint: null,
  message: 'relation "public.characters" does not exist'
}
Error: PostgrestError: Could not find a relationship between 'subscriptions' and 'prices' in the schema cache
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@supabase/postgrest-js/dist/module/PostgrestBuilder.js:136:27)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async getSubscription (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./lib/supabase-server.ts:55:40)
    at async Promise.all (index 2)
    at async Home (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./app/page.tsx:23:66) {
  details: "Searched for a foreign key relationship between 'subscriptions' and 'prices' in the schema 'public', but no matches were found.",
  hint: null,
  code: 'PGRST200'
}
Since you haven't set a value for `useCdn`, we will deliver content using our global, edge-cached API-CDN. If you wish to have content delivered faster, set `useCdn: false` to use the Live API. Note: You may incur higher costs using the live API.
 ⨯ components/input-form.tsx (56:56) @ InputForm
 ⨯ TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '0')
    at InputForm (./components/input-form.tsx:60:97)
  54 |   const [popoverWidth, setPopoverWidth] = useState("0px");
  55 |   const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
> 56 |   const [character, setCharacter] = useState(characters[0]);
     |                                                        ^
  57 |   const [images, setImages] = useState(characters[0].images);
  58 |
  59 |   const lastClickedCharacterRef = useRef(null); // Ref to store the last clicked character
 ○ Compiling /favicon.ico ...


I have not set up a PostgreSQL database, I am not sure if Supabase handles that? I think the error could be due to the fact that my connection might not be pointing to the right database, or there might not be a database that exists at all. It could also be a permissions issue?
Also, if it is one of the aforementioned issues, is it possible to use like a placeholder value just so the project can run locally without error? Right now I just want to see the project's front end and play around with it.

Can you share the repo you are following? Seems that you forgot to seed the DB.
